# How to estimate the Median Survival Time if the survival curve does not drop to 50%?

Tags: survival

I fitted my model using Cox Proportional Hazard Regression.

I have found that if the survival curve does not drop to 50% then the median survival time is undefined.

I simply want to know if I can still estimate the median survival time if the survival curve is not less than 50%, or if there is an alternative if median survival time is undefined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [alternative way to compute or infer median from survival curve](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/200560/alternative-way-to-compute-or-infer-median-from-survival-curve) If you are willing to fit a parametric survival function like a Weibull model then you can get a median survival estimate. You might be better off using a different survival quantile, like 75% survival, to avoid the underlying assumptions and extrapolation needed for getting a median from a parametric model.